# Android studio error Java Class

Tags: android-studio

I'm new in android studios and I don't speak or write english well , but I trust here I gonna find a answer, I tried to add a Java Class but I have a problem.....

"Unable to parse template "Class"
Error message: Cannot modify a read-only directory 'C:\Users\======\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar!\android\database\sqlite'."

this happens when I try to create a java class with "SQLiteOpenHelper"

Comment: have you tried run the Android Studio as administrator? (right click -> run as admin)

Comment: Oh, try using a real device instead of an emulator.

Comment: ok yes , I tried but didn't work